# IQKeyboardManagerSwift 'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

Installing `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` via CocoaPods works, but when I build my project I get multiple build time errors saying the following:

> 'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

Why is this happening? I have tried different versions of the library. I am on Xcode v10.2.1.

Comment: Did you use 'shared' in extension?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that you are using extensions in your app. Try setting `Require Only App-Extension_safe API` to **No** inside your `Pods` project for the IQKeyboardManagerSwift target.

[image: Image of setting]

Comment: I am writing an iMessage extension...will this still work?